# Evaluating a function at a specific point

Tags: python, function

I am trying to write a Python function called term_output that can evaluate what a single term equals at a value of  x .

For example, when  `x=2` , the term  `3x^2 = 3*2^2=12`.
I've been told to represent  `3x^2`  in code as (3, 2), and:
`term_output((3, 2), 2)` should return `12`.

I am trying to use solely functions (and functions of functions)

```
def term(x,y):
    return x**y

def term_output(term,z):
    return term*z
```

My end result is `(3, 2, 3, 2)`.

But I have tried many options and i expect the output to return 12

Comment: Are you sure the instructions are to write a function `term_output` with those exact inputs?

Comment: Start your Python and enter `(3,2) * 2`. It will look familiar. Then try `(3,2) * 3`, `(3,2) * 4`...

Comment: (3,2) * 2 gives me the same answer, (3, 2, 3, 2) that I don't want

Comment: @CarterB That's because `term_output((3,2), 2)` *is* `(3,2) * 2`.

Answer (score 1):

`term` is a pair, not a number, and multiplying any tuple duplicates it.

```
>>> (1,2) * 3
(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2)
>>> (1,2) * 4
(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2)
```

You need to take apart the pair.
I think simultaneous assignment is convenient (and it documents the intent better than indexing):

```
>>> a = (3,2)
>>> a
(3, 2)
>>> x,y = a
>>> x
3
>>> y
2
```

Putting it in a function:

```
def term_output(term,z):
    coefficent, exponent = term
    return coefficient * z ** exponent
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure according to @CarterB 's example, you should switch between `z` and `exponent`. For this specific example it works because they are the same

Comment: @TomerKalish No, `term_output((a,b), x)` should be `a * x ** b`, not `a * b ** x`. Your solution only works for this specific example because they are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Simply as:

```
x = 2
y = 2
z = 3
xy = [x,y]

def term(xy):
    return xy[0]**xy[1]

def term_output(xy,z):
    return term(xy)*z
```

Comment: the result should be that term_output((3, 2), 2) returns 12, in your case when I try I get term_output() missing 1 required positional argument: 'z'

Comment: Your `term_output` receives 3 arguments. The original receives 2

Comment: @CarterB here you go

Comment: result is 18. you should replace the operators. `term_output` should have `**` and `term` should have `*`.